# Offset/Fetch Query Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, fetch, offset

I have a SQL Server query that is performing poorly when retrieving data via pagination using offset/fetch. The earlier pages return results very fast but later ones are extremely slow and creating a bottleneck in our system. It's joining on two temp tables (#A and #T). Here is a pared down version of the query:

```
    Select
        I.CustomerID,
        I.InvoiceID,
        I.ItemID,
        TI1.TrackID as TrackID1,
        TI1.ItemName as ItemName1,
        TI1.TrackCatID as TrackCatID1,
        TI1.CategoryName as CategoryName1,
        TI2.TrackID as TrackID2,
        TI2.ItemName as ItemName2,
        TI2.TrackCatID as TrackCatID2,
        TI2.CategoryName as CategoryName2,
        A.AccID,
        A.Name as AccountName,
        A.utimestamp as UpdateTimeStamp
    FROM 
        #A A
            Inner Join [dbo].[Item] I WITH(FORCESEEK)
                On 
                A.CustomerID = I.CustomerID And
                A.AccountID = I.AccountID
            Left Join #T TI1 On
                I.CustomerID = TI1.CustomerID And
                I.TrackID1 = TI1.TrackID
            Left Join #T TI2 On
                I.CustomerID = TI2.CustomerID And
                I.TrackID2 = TI2.TrackID
    Order by
        A.utimestamp
    Offset 0 Rows Fetch Next 1000 Rows Only
```

Where the temp tables are defined as:

```
Create table #T (CustomerID uniqueidentifier, TrackCatID uniqueidentifier, TrackID uniqueidentifier, ItemName varchar(100), CategoryName varchar(100),PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID,TrackID))

Create table #A (CustomerID uniqueidentifier, AccountID uniqueidentifier, Name varchar(100), utimestamp timestamp, PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, AccountID))
```

Regarding the DB table [dbo].[Item] it is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item](
        [Sequence] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [CustomerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [ItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
        [AccountID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [TrackID1] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
        [TrackID2] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Item] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [ItemID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [CX_Item] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC,
    [Sequence] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And has a number of indexes that each have have several columns:

Item Indexes

```
1: CusotmerID, Sequence 
2: CusotmerID, AccountId, Sequence 
3: CusotmerID, TrackId1 
4: CusotmerID, TrackId2 
5: CusotmerID, ItemID
```

Is there something I'm missing that's causing the later paginated queries to be slow? Note: The 0 in "Offset 0 Rows" increases by 1000 for every page. 
Also, I added a index to the temp table #A and didn't see an improvement to the results:
CREATE INDEX IDX_Timestamp ON #A(utimestamp)

Comment: you are ordering by (and thus doing the fetch/offset on) utimestamp -- this does not have an index.  Every query needs to order the entire table. First one just needs smallest 1K, second needs smallest 2K, 3rd need 3 etc.  Clearly the platform (you don't say which it is) is optimized to return first N rows.  Make utimestamp an index and it should all be the same.

Comment: you say sql server in the title, my bad.

Comment: I forgot to mention in original post (will edit) that I had added an index to the timestamp temp table but it didn't change the results.

Comment: I guess I didn't see that it was a temp table.  Not going to help to add an index on a temp table.  How big is this temp table?  Something about this story does not make sense since the temp table would need to be much larger than the number of rows you are selecting --OR is the real issue that when you create the temp table you create all the rows up to pageselect*1000?  Then of course it will be slower you are creating 1000 more rows for each page.

Comment: If this is the case move the offset and fetch into the code that creates the temp table.  That big a temp table might cause your system to thrash if it is resource constrained too.

Comment: Neither the temp tables #A or #T are very big. But the actual DB table is massive with > 1M rows.

Comment: That comment ignores the issue -- your query won't work on page 3 if #A has less than 4000 rows.  It also won't work on page 20 if #A has less than 21000 rows.  #A has to grow with the page number.  Your question is "Why is my query getting slower with the growth of page number?"  This is the answer.

Comment: Also, IMO > 1M is not massive, just large.